# React.js - Close and add another row div after X items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm learning React.js.

I have this code:

```
const articles = Object
      .keys(this.state.articles)
      .map(key => <ArticleThumb key={key} details={this.state.articles[key]} />)
;

return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        { articles }
      </div>
    </div>
)
```

Assuming I have 6 items, here is the code after rendering:

```
<div className="container">
  <div className="row">
    <div id="item1"></div>
    <div id="item2"></div>
    <div id="item3"></div>
    <div id="item4"></div>
    <div id="item5"></div>
    <div id="item6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I want to have only 3 items per line like this:

```
<div className="container">
  <div className="row">
    <div id="item1"></div>
    <div id="item2"></div>
    <div id="item3"></div>
  </div>
  <div className="row">
    <div id="item4"></div>
    <div id="item5"></div>
    <div id="item6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer is to use something like lodash's chunk function https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#chunk

However, if you are not using npm and or do not want to add additional dependencies you are going to have to use a good old fashioned javascript for loop to perform the grouping you need.

Answer (score 0):

With the markup you have you could do it via css:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row {
  width: 33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a ArticleGrid component:

```
class ArticleGrid extends Component {

  render() {
    let articlesRows = Object
      .keys(this.props.rows)
      .map(key => <ArticleRow key={key} articles={this.props.rows[key]} />)
    ;

    return (
      <div id="articles" className="container">
        {articlesRows}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ArticleGrid;
```

A ArticleRow component:

```
class ArticleRow extends Component {

  render() {
    let articles = Object
      .keys(this.props.articles)
      .map(key => <ArticleThumb key={key} details={this.props.articles[key]} />)
    ;

    return (
      <div className="row">
        {articles}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ArticleRow;
```

I used lodash's chunk and values function (ty Deadron) and it's done:

```
let articles = _.values(this.state.articles);
let articlesRows = _.chunk(articles, 3);
return (<ArticleGrid rows={articlesRows} />);
```